# jQuery conditional if not in loop

Tags: jquery, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

How can I add a conditional to the end of a For loop?

**Example:**

```
if (state) {
    for (var i = 0, l = $imageLength; i < l; i++) {
        if ($images[i].url === state) {
            rGallery.init(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Need to add here: if NOT in loop... blah*/

} else {
    rGallery.init();
}
```

Side note, could also improve the logic to avoid it... if (state has a match in the loop) init(i) else init()

Comment: if you need condition tha you can use do-while loop in do while loop we check condition at the end of loop

Comment: Are you trying to tell whether you go to the end by the loop finishing or by the `break;` statement?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

What about using a boolean variable :

```
var hasMatch = false;
if (state){
    for (var i = 0, l = $imageLength; i < l; i++){
        if ($images[i].url === state){
            rGallery.init(i);
            hasMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if(!hasMatch){
    rGallery.init();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use another variable as a flag and check it after the loop:

```js
var found = false;
if (state){
    for (var i = 0, l = $imageLength; i < l; i++){
        if ($images[i].url === state){
            rGallery.init(i);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (!found){
    rGallery.init();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag if the result is found in the loop or not:

```
var found = false;
for (var i = 0, l = $imageLength; i < l; i++){

    if ($images[i].url === state){

        rGallery.init(i);
        fount = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    /* Need to add here: if NOT in loop... blah*/
}
```